# Android gradle: Get selected build variant / build type

Tags: android, gradle

I am writing a gradle plugin.

How can I get programmatically the selected build variant?

Comment: AFAIK there is no such thing. The model contains all build variants, and depending on which tasks you invoke, one or more variants get built.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `getBuildDir()` method of `org.gradle.api.Project`. It gives you the build root directory of Android Studio. Inside it you need to search for `BuildConfig.java` and inside this file you will find it

```
public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "Eureka";
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `BuildConfig` for that, but make sure you import the right BuildConfig, that should have your project package as prefix in imports.

`BuildConfig` provide you information about build type, build variant, if you are or not in a debug build, among other things.

Check this for more information about Gradle: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips.